# Laravel route issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

i cannot figure out, why the links that i generate using the Laravel route() function, does not look like i want.

Here is the lines code of my Routes.php

```
Route::get('/market/announcements/show/{period}/{date}', array('as' => 'market.announcements.index', 'uses' => 'AnnouncementsController@index'));
Route::get('/market/announcements/history', array('as' => 'market.announcements.history', 'uses' => 'AnnouncementsController@history'));
Route::resource('market/announcements', 'AnnouncementsController');
```

Here is how i generate the links:

```
route('market.announcements.index', ['period' => $key, 'date' => $link])
```

Unfortunately the generated link is: 
    market/announcements?period=year&date=2016

Instead of:
    market/announcements/show/year/2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because

```php
Route::resource('market/announcements', 'AnnouncementsController');
```

overwrites route

```php
Route::get('/market/announcements/show/{period}/{date}', array('as' => 'market.announcements.index', 'uses' => 'AnnouncementsController@index'));
```

If you'd run `php artisan route:list` you'd see

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Method    | URI                                       | Name                         |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| POST      | market/announcements                      | market.announcements.store   |
| GET|HEAD  | market/announcements                      | market.announcements.index   |
| GET|HEAD  | market/announcements/create               | market.announcements.create  |
| GET|HEAD  | market/announcements/history              | market.announcements.history |
| GET|HEAD  | market/announcements/show/{period}/{date} | market.announcements.index   |
| GET|HEAD  | market/announcements/{announcements}      | market.announcements.show    |
| PUT|PATCH | market/announcements/{announcements}      | market.announcements.update  |
| DELETE    | market/announcements/{announcements}      | market.announcements.destroy |
| GET|HEAD  | market/announcements/{announcements}/edit | market.announcements.edit    |
```

See `market.announcements.index` listed twice? `Router` take the last one.

Now if you comment out a resource in the routes file for a moment

```php
// Route::resource('market/announcements', 'AnnouncementsController');
```

and would try it in `tinker` you'd see your route now works as expected

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.6.19 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> route('market.announcements.index', ['period' => 'year', 'date' => 2016]);
=> "http://localhost/market/announcements/show/year/2016"
```

Comment: aa thanks. I have changed the order and now it works :)